# javascript unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compress my JavaScript code to get less traffic on my site. It has been working fine, but now I came across an error I can't resolve.

I turned my ajax function into one line:

```
function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}xmlhttp.open("GET","data/"+id+".html",true);xmlhttp.send();}
```

But the chrome console tells me there is an unexpected identifier on this line. Firefox says there is an semicolon missing on this line.

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong, but I can't find the error, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Helps to uncompress : http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you have a `}` too many. Anyway, compressing yourself tends to result in errors.

```
function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
} // <-- end function?
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/" + id + ".html", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Use [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) instead.

Comment: Also common to get this same error for missing comma in an Object.

Comment: And those tend to be missing after object properties, especially when you add/move variables/functions inside an object.

Comment: In my case it was caused by having `if diff < 0 {` instead of `if (diff < 0) {`

Answer (score 11):

I recommend using http://jsbeautifier.org/ - if you paste your code snippet into it and press beautify, the error is immediately visible.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. What is the error?

Answer (score 4):

In such cases, you are better off re-adding the whitespace which makes the syntax error immediate apparent:

```
function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","data/"+id+".html",true);xmlhttp.send();
}
```

There's a } too many. Also, after the closing } of the function, you should add a ; before the xmlhttp.open()

And finally, I don't see what that anonymous function does up there. It's never executed or referenced. Are you sure you pasted the correct code?

Answer (score 2):

Either remove one } from end of `responseText;}}` or from the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an extra curly bracket in the code.

```
function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
// extra bracket }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/" + id + ".html", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compress JS, I recommend you to use [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), a tool provided by Google for website developers. It also provides additional APIs that can be implemented by yourself